# Showing progressbar while loading data from arraylist to listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView inside an AlertDialog that comes after clicking on another ListView. The flow looks something like this:

[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhNMi.png)

The screenshot above is the MainActivity. Clicking on any iten on this list will bring this dialog below:

[Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W86LL.png)

But the problem is, the dialog box contains a listview inside listview. So, it takes some seconds to load the view. So, I was trying to show a progress dialog before loading the view. So, I did something like this:

```
            ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("loading");
            pd.show();

            ArrayList<Teacher> teachers = subs.get(position).getTeachers();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
            builder.setView(v);

            ListView listViewDialog = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_lv);
            TesAdapter adapter1 = new TesAdapter(MainActivity.this, teachers);
            listViewDialog.setAdapter(adapter1);
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listViewDialog.setDivider(null);

            pd.hide();
            builder.show();
```

But the Progress dialog is not showing & still it was taking more time to load the alert dialog. So, I tried this code:

```
            final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("loading");
            pd.show();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            final View v = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
            builder.setView(v);
            builder.show();


            AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayList<Teacher> teachers = subs.get(position).getTeachers();
                    ListView listViewDialog = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_lv);
                    TesAdapter adapter1 = new TesAdapter(MainActivity.this, teachers);
                    listViewDialog.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listViewDialog.setDivider(null);
                    pd.hide();
                }
            });
```

But got this error:

```
WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked
```

Any solution? Thanks in advance...

Comment: instead of pd.hide, try using pd.dismiss

Comment: Still the same...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use expandable RecyclerView which handles all the exceptions that you are facing. Please check this [link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view). It is a neat design and solves your problem. Let me know

Comment: I understand that you do not want to rework on the module. But try having a look at the link I sent you. It is really a neat implementation and even the layout will be neat and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change pd.hide to pd.dismiss and  add pd.dismiss in the onPause of the activity too

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to access UI element from worker thread. UI part must be execute from the Main Thread Like this :

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                ArrayList<Teacher> teachers = subs.get(position).getTeachers();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ListView listViewDialog = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_lv);
                        TesAdapter adapter1 = new TesAdapter(MainActivity.this, teachers);
                        listViewDialog.setAdapter(adapter1);
                        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listViewDialog.setDivider(null);
                        pd.dismiss(); // CHANGE HERE
                    }
                });


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

User async task for this entire process. Show dialog in  `onPreExecute()` and dismiss the dialog and set data to listview through adapter in `onPostExecute()` . Do other operations on data in `doInBackGround()`. Remember not to perform any UI related operations in `doInBackGround()`.

Comment: Can you please provide the whole code of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to use Recycler view inspite of using listview, and as per your question you can use Expandable recycler view in the dialog, there are many libraries available for ex: https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view